# Cache URL issues in React project for Mobile only

Tags: reactjs, url, caching, mobile

I am trying to display a list of similar components which lead to unique pages in my react app. I have each card component linked via a tag's to a distinct page with it's own unique ID.
Basically these cards (when clicked) lead to posts such as [www.baseurl.com/posts/:id](http://www.baseurl.com/posts/:id)
so:
[www.baseurl.com/posts/1](http://www.baseurl.com/posts/1)
[www.baseurl.com/posts/2](http://www.baseurl.com/posts/2)

Display a list of Cards

```
{Object.keys(PostData).map((entry, index) => (
    <PostCard
       key={index}
       post_id={index} // index works just fine since I am starting from 0 in my database
    />
))}
```

PostCard component renders this html filled with a tags

```
<a
   id={`${post_id}`} // I hoped adding this would help but so far it hasn't
   data-cy={`{post_id}`} // I hoped adding this would help but so far it hasn't
   href={`www.baseurl.com/posts/${post_id}`}
>
   {title for the Card}
</a>
```

Routes for the app work just fine

```
  <Route path="/posts/:id" component={Post} /> // shows post data
  <Route path="/posts" component={PostsParent} /> // shows all cards
```

These PostCards lead to a unique url but chrome, safari, and aloha browsers keep directing me to the same page on Mobile. I've tried opening new tabs but it hasn't quite resolved my issue via target="_blank".
I think this problem is unique to mobile since my computer renders it just fine. 
How could I begin to fix this? Is it a cache problem?

Comment: Have you already tried putting http:// in the path? maybe it's just replacing the link and not redirecting. ... href={`http://www.baseurl.com/posts/${post_id}`} or only use `/posts/${post_id}`

Comment: @andresmartinez Thank you for the input. That's actually how I have it set up! My href's point to http:baseurl.com/posts/${post_id}. I've actually been omitting the hashrouter so there /#/ between .com/ and /post_id as I don't think it's relevant.